# Parsing colunas de números de um arquivo CSV em C

Tags: c, array, csv, float, parser

Olá, Boa Noite

Estou com um arquivo .CSV simples, contendo apenas duas colunas, separadas por vírgula e pela a nova linha, como exemplo:

```
0.001,-9.623
0.098,2.540
1.000,-1.002
```

E preciso separa-los preferencialmente em dois vetores, ou em uma matriz (2 colunas por 1300 linhas). Tentei trocar as vírgulas por espaços em brancos porém não deu, como na fração

```
for(n = 0; n <= AMOSTRAS_LINHAS, n++)
{
    fscanf(amostras, "%f %f", &tempo[n], &tensao[n])
}
```

O resultado de impressão é sempre zero pra ambos, eu sei que o problema se encontra no fscanf, porém já não consigo enxergar, também existe a possibilidade do uso do strtok(), porém também não enxerguei uma solução com o mesmo, caso alguém possa elucidar em como abordar o problema, agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se cada valor está separado por uma virgula, basta indicar isso no `fscanf`. Altere-o para:

```
fscanf(amostras, "%f,%f", &tempo[n], &tensao[n])
//                  ^--- virgula
```

Aviso no entanto que o seu `for` tem o fim com `<=` que irá correr mais uma vez que o que pretende, e tem uma `,` onde deveria ter `;`:

```
for(n = 0; n <= AMOSTRAS_LINHAS, n++)
//            ^                ^
//            |-- devia ser <  |
//                             |--- devia ser ;
```

Melhor opção que guardar a quantidade de linhas é ir lendo enquanto houverem linhas. Isso é facil de fazer se trocar o seu `for` por um `while` com a condição correta:

```
FILE* amostras = fopen("amostras.txt", "r");
float tempo, tensao;

while (fscanf(amostras, "%f,%f", &tempo, &tensao) == 2){
    printf("%f %f\n", tempo, tensao);
}
```

No `while` faço executar enquanto houverem dois valores lidos.

Veja o resultado de execução na minha maquina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, soluções que encontrava eram baseadas em strtok. Forte abraço.