# C separar string com vírgulas em vetores

Tags: c, array, string, arquivo, path-separator

Quero separar cada linha de um arquivo em 2 vetores: v[i].date and v[i].value.
Porém, quando rodo o código nenhum valor que imprimo está correto, e os outputs sao valores aleatórios.
Há algo que eu deveria mudar?

> Input
>   02/20/18,11403.7
>   02/19/18,11225.3
>   02/18/18,10551.8
>   02/17/18,11112.7
>   02/16/18,10233.9

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct
{
    char *date;
    long int *value;
}vetor;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *btc;

    if((btc=fopen("BTC.csv", "r")) == NULL  )
    {
        printf("not found btc\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    long int a=0;

    char linha[256];
    char *token = NULL;

    while (fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), btc) != 0)
    { 
            a++;
    }

    vetor *v;

    v=(vetor*)malloc(a*sizeof(vetor));

    char linha2[256];

    while (fgets(linha2, sizeof(linha2), btc) != 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            fscanf(btc,"%[^,]s",v[i].date);
            fscanf(btc,"%d[^,]",&v[i].value);
            fseek(btc, +1, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }

    fclose(btc);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não seria equivalente a [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c)?

Comment: Também... note que você esta lendo o arquivo 2x. Na segunda passada você deve voltar ao inicio do arquivo.. tente utilizar a função `rewind(btc)` para voltar o arquivo ao estado inicial antes do segundo while.

Comment: Amigo, fiz uma pergunta similar ontem, e obtive uma boa resposta, que pode lhe ajudar nisso ai também, já que são apenas duas colunas. [Parsing colunas de números de um arquivo CSV em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/284913/parsing-colunas-de-n%C3%BAmeros-de-um-arquivo-csv-em-c/284917#284917)

Answer (score 0):

Em sua estrutura vetor você define dois ponteiros: um ponteiro para char (date) e outro ponteiro para long int (value).
Para efetivamente armazenar os valores lidos você precisa alocar o espaço necessário e fazer com que cada um destes ponteiros aponte para o espaço de memória respectivo.